# Generating Very Large Complex JSON Files using Spring Batch

Tags: json, spring-batch

I have data in Mongo DB in following collections: Client, Client_Organization, Payroll_Run & Worker. The relation among the Objects is **Client & Olient_Organization are 1:M**, **Client_Organization & Payroll_Execution are 1:M**. The **Worker** element is an array under the **Client_Organization**

The sample JSON to be generated is as below:

```
"Client": {
  "name":"",
  "ID":"", // other fields omitted for brevity
  "Client_Organization": [{
    "ID":"",
    "name":"",
    "address":"",
    "Payroll_Execution": [{
       "ID":"",
       "date":"" // other fields
        }] // end of Payroll_Execution
    "worker": [{
        // several nested JSON elements
        "ID":"",
        "payStubDetails": {
            },
        "dependents": [{
            }],
        "benefits": {
            }
    }]
    }] // end Client_Org 
} // end of Client
```

For a large client the number of elements in Worker array can be as much as 300K. I am assessing Spring Batch to generate such a JSON file. How can I apply chunk based processing on the Worker array element so that I do not overflow the memory.

Per my understanding if I join the data from the collections then I would only be processing 1 client's data and commit-interval would work on the root element  of the JSON object (**i.e. Client**) passed to the writer. What can be other approaches to address this use case using Spring Batch?

Answer (score 1):

The `JsonFileItemWriter` generates a json file with the following format:

```
[
   {jsonObject1},
   {jsonObject2},
   ...
   {jsonObjectN}
]
```

Items will be marshalled to json using a `JsonObjectMarshaller` (Spring Batch provides marshallers based on Jackson and Gson out-of-the-box). So if you are planning to use this writer, you need to make sure that items correspond to "root" json objects in the output file. In your case, if items are `Client` instances, you need to do a join to prepare items with all details that need to be marshalled as part of root json objects.

Comment: Thanks Mahmoud for the valuable information. I wanted to ask "Will the append flag be honoured by JsonFileItemWriter when writing nested JSON elements in individual batch job steps?" I.e. I create a separate step for Pay_Execution and Worker data elements and latter step append to the same file.

Comment: No, you can't append nested items. I would try to find a way to prepare items before writing them instead of using multiple steps.